# How mutiiple async NSURLConnection handles internally

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

I am curious to know how multiple async `NSURLConnection` connections handles internally ? I know they use an internal background thread to run it but lets say if in code i am creating two async `NSURLConnection` concurrently , does that will create two thread internally to run them in parllel or second connection will wait for first to complete ? In brief please confrim how multiple async `NSURLConnection` achieve concurrency ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it will run in parallel. You can have a look on WWDC Session Video about network programming.

Apple engineer said handling url request one by one is expensive, running them in parallel is much more reasonable. The reason is, for processing a request, actually most of the time is spent on latency, not logic processing in devices and servers. So, handling requests parallel will efficiently reduce time waste for latency.

so I guess they wont do async NSURLConnection one by one because it's contradicting this basic theory.

Besides, I have tried to download images Async using NSURLConnection. I sent out a few request once. like

```
for ( i = 1 to 4) {
    send request i 
 }
```

The response is also not in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Each async `NSURLConnection` runs on it's own thread after you start the connection (async `NSURLConnection` has to be created and started on main thread!) and their delegate and datadelegate methods called on main thread.

Comment: okie, you mean to say for each NSURLConnection one thread will be created internally ? So, is there any max limit of async NSURLConnection can be created concurrently ?

Answer (score 0):

Other option that you can use it as using "NSOperationQueue" and execute request using NSOperations. Please refer http://www.icodeblog.com/2012/10/19/tutorial-asynchronous-http-client-using-nsoperationqueue/ for more detail.

Thanks,
Jim